# Callback Functions in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am used to Javascript where I can simply pass a function as a parameter to use as a callback later. It was nice and easy.

Now I am writing an app in c# and would like to accomplish the same thing.

Basically, my app is like the following and requires an authentication token. However, at the getData stage, if the token is expired, I need to call refreshToken(). How do I pass the callback function through refreshToken() so getData knows what to call when the token is refreshed?

Here's a diagram of what I would do in Javascript, but would I go about doing this in C#, or just passing callbacks in general?:

```
getData(callback);
// Looks like the token is expired, exiting the getData function and refreshing token
refreshToken(function(){ getData(callback); });
// Token is refreshed, now call getData()
getData(callback);
// Callback is run
```

Or, alternatively, instead of using a ton of callbacks I could do the refreshToken call synchronously. However, RestSharp on WP7 for whatever reason isn't showing Execute, just ExecuteAsync, which is what I use now. Does anyone know why this method doesn't seem to exist for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no synchronous web calls in silverlight / wp7, so that is not a restsharp problem.

As arthur said you want delegates.

```
function getData(Action<string> callback) {
  if (token.needRefresh) {
    refrshToken(() => getData(callback) );
    return;
  }
  // get Data
  callback(data);
}

function refreshToken(Action callback) {
  // token.refresh
  callback();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To pass a function as a parameter in C# one uses a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). A delegate specifies the expected return type and arguments of the function being passed into a method and your callback method must conform to this specification, otherwise your code will not compile.

Delegates are generally declared directly within a namespace and take the form:

`<access modifier(s)> delegate <return type> <DelegateName>([argument list]);`

For example, in C# a delegate named FooCallback representing a callback function for the Foo method that takes no arguments and returns void would look like this:

```
namespace Demo
{
public delegate void FooCallback();
}
```

A function that takes a FooCallback parameter would look like this:

```
namespace Demo
{
//delegate for a FooCallback method from the previous code block
public delegate void FooCallback();

public class Widget
{
public void BeginFoo(FooCallback callback)
{

}
```

Asssuming that you have a method that matches the signature of a delegate you can simply pass it's name as the value of the delegate parameter. For example, assuming you have a function named `MyFooCallback`  you can pass it as a parameter to the `StartFoo` method like this:

```
using Demo; //Needed to access the FooDelegate and Widget class.

namespace YourApp
{
public class WidgetUser
{
private Widget widget; //initialization skipped for brevity.

private void MyFooCallback()
{
//This is our callback method for StartFoo. Note that it has a void return type
//and no parameters, just like the definition of FooCallback. The signature of
//the method you pass as a delegate parameter MUST match the definition of the
//delegate, otherwise you get a compile-time error.
}
public void UseWidget()
{
//Call StartFoo, passing in `MyFooCallback` as the value of the callback parameter.
widget.BeginFoo(MyFooCallback);
}
}
}
```

While it is possible to define a delegate with arguments, it is not possible to pass an argument list alongside the method name as one normally does when invoking a method

```
namespace Demo
{
 public delegate void FrobCallback(int frobberID);
//Invalid Syntax - Can't pass in parameters to the delegate method this way.
BeginFrob(MyFrobCallback(10))
}
```

When a delegate specifies parameters, the method that invokes the delegate takes the arguments needed by the delegate and passes them to the delegate method when it is called:

`BeginFrob(MyFrobCallback, 10)`

The BeginFrob method would then invoke the MyFrobCallback with the passed in frobberID value of 10 like this:

```
public void BeginFrob(FrobCallback callback, int frobberID)
{
//...do stuff before the callback
callback(frobberID);
}
```

[Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) allow you to define a method where it is used rather than needing to explicitly declare it

`BeginFoo((int frobberID) => {your callback code here;});`

In summary, delegates are a means for methods to be passed to other methods as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [anonymous delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)